# "biggest or smallest number so far" c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that reads in a number from the user, and then tells the user if it is the greatest number so far. I have tried a couple of ideas but none of them worked(Program runs but not the right way). Much gratefull for any help! Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
int main()
{
    double num1 =0,num2=0;
    cout<<"Please enter a number: \n";


    while (cin>>num1){
        cout<<num1<<" is the greatest number so far\n";

        cout<<" Enter a new number: \n";
        cin>>num2;
        if(num2>num1)
            cout<<num2<<" is the greatest number so far. \n";
        else
            cout<<num1<<" is still the greatest number.\n";
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end.

Comment: In what sense does this not work?

Comment: Forgot to paste it in, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, the prrogram does work, just not the way I want it to. I am doing an excercise from a c++ learning book. It is the following task: "Each time around the loop, write out the value entered. If its the biggest so far, write out - the biggest so far after the number".

Comment: Run the program in the debugger, or sprinkle output statements everywhere that show what the values of num1 and num2 are.

Comment: "runs but not the right way" doesn't tell us anything useful. What should it print, and what is it printing instead?

Comment: Most books (or even some intro classes) don't tell you this, but 80% of programming is not writing code -- it's debugging it. If you're using an integrated development environment (Visual Studio, Xcode, etc.) just put a breakpoint on the first line of the function and hit the debug button, then click the "step over" button and inspect the values of your variables until you see the pattern of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading two numbers each time through the loop. One in `while (cin >> num1)` and then again in `cin >> num2`. You should only read one number each time, after you print the message asking for the new number.

You're also printing the message saying that `num1` is the greatest at the top of the loop, before you've compared it with anything. I think that was intended just for the first number entered, so it should be outside the loop.

When the new number is larger than the greatest so far, you need to make it take the place of that number.

And learn to use meaningful variable names. It's hard to remember the difference between `num1` and `num2` -- names like `greatest` and `next` make their purpose clear.

```
int main()
{
    double greatest, next;
    cout<<"Please enter a number: \n";
    cin >> greatest;
    cout<< greatest << " is the greatest number so far\n";

    while (true){
        cout<<" Enter a new number: \n";
        cin>>next;
        if(next > greatest) {
            cout << next << " is the greatest number so far. \n";
            greatest = next;
        } else {
            cout << greatest << " is still the greatest number.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I will be more precise next time.

Answer (score 0):

Must store biggest number.

```
int main()
{
    double num1 =0,num2=0;
    cout<<"Please enter a number: \n";


    while (cin>>num1){
        cout<<num1<<" is the greatest number so far\n";

        cout<<" Enter a new number: \n";
        cin>>num2;
        if(num2>num1) {
            num1 = num2;
            cout<<num2<<" is the greatest number so far. \n";
        }
        else
            cout<<num1<<" is still the greatest number.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This has some of the same bugs as the original.

Answer (score -1):

Use a variable for the value, and one for the largest so far. The loop could be simplified:

```
int main()
{
    double num = 0, greatest = 0;

    while(cout << "Please enter a number: \n", cin >> num){
        if(num > greatest) {
            greatest = num;
            cout << num << " is the greatest number so far\n";
        }
        else
            cout << greatest << " is still the greatest number.\n";
    }
}
```